# exception android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast class

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a problem, my app generate this exception,and i don't understand.
I have implement the multiDexEnabled in my build.gradle

```
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast to com.example.AnalyticsApplication
```

**My Class Java**

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

 private Tracker mTracker;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

  //Analitycs
  AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
  mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
  mTracker.setScreenName("Splash");
  mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

}

**file Gradle**

```
 defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activityandroid:name=".Splash">
<intent-filter>
<actionandroid:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<categoryandroid:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: post your manifest file too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should extend the `AnalyticsApplication` class into your own class, like this:

```
public class YourApplicationName extends AnalyticsApplication {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

          //Analitycs
          AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
          mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
          mTracker.setScreenName("Splash");
          mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
     }

     // Here you will enable Multidex
     @Override
     protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
          super.attachBaseContext(base);
          MultiDex.install(getBaseContext());
     }

}
```

After this, you must change your `AndroidManifest.xml` file to this:

```
<application
     android:name="path.to.YourApplicationName"
     ...
```

Please, check this link for more information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDex.html

Comment: what type of AnalyticsApplication ? how it could be instead of activity

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue this cause of you set `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` in your manifest so your application call is type of `MultiDexApplication`

```
<application
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activityandroid:name=".Splash">
<intent-filter>
<actionandroid:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<categoryandroid:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter></activity>
</application>
```

my application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {


    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, // tracker used only in this app
        GLOBAL_TRACKER, // tracker used by all the apps from a company . eg: roll-up tracking.
        ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company .
    }

    public HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<>();

    public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker tracker = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER)?analytics.newTracker(Property_ID)
                    : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
                    : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
            mTrackers.put(trackerId , tracker);
        }
        return  mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }


    private Activity mCurrentActivity = null;

    public void setCurrentActivity(Activity mCurrectActivity) {
        this.mCurrentActivity = mCurrectActivity;
    }

    public Activity getCurrentActivity() {
        return mCurrentActivity;
    }

    private static Context mAppContext;

    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MultiDex.install(this);
        mInstance = this;
        this.setAppContext(getApplicationContext());
    }

    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return mAppContext;
    }

    public void setAppContext(Context mAppContext) {
        this.mAppContext = mAppContext;
    }

}
```

this why when I call this method (initialize application instance ) it crash , it try cast `MultiDexApplication` to `MyApplication`

```
MyApplication application = (MyApplication)getApplication();
```

so to fix this issue just change your manifest attribute name to MyApplication

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".MyApplication"> // add path to your application class here
```

Comment: Excellent explanation, simple solution, worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

You should extend your `Application` class from `MultidexApplication` and use it in manifest instead of using `android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication` directly.

Answer (score 2):

There are several correct solutions here. But, if you're using react-native >= `0.60` or you're using `androidx` then this is the solution:

```
// MainApplication

...
import androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

...    

public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements ReactApplication {

    ...
}
```

Comment: Working answer for React-Native `>= 0.60`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove that line

```
 android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

from manifest file and put your Application name . i.e

```
 android:name="com.yourAppNamae.activity.YourApplicationName"
```

That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

To React Native:

```
// MainApplication

...

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;

...    

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(getBaseContext());
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to extend your `MainApplication` by `Multidex` -> `public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements ReactApplication {`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the @Chandan answer, really keeping your original app android:name at AndroidManifest.xml make it works (at least with my case, RN > 0.60 and using Androidx).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was no `android:name` for my `application` tag in my manifest in the first place, and the app had previously built and run successfully hundreds of times. Finally I tried simply uninstalling the app from the device and rebuild/reinstall, and it went back to working as normal.