# Exception MultiDexApplication Cannot be Cast to Class from getApplication()

Tags: java, android, gradle, classcastexception, android-multidex

I have followed the answer here, yet it is not changing anything:

[exception android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658796/exception-android-support-multidex-multidexapplication-cannot-be-cast-class)

I have a MyApplication class that extends MultiDexApplication. In my main activity I am calling getApplication() and casting it to (MyApplication). My manifest has the name of the application set to .MyApplication. This is in Android Studio. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.gametest.gametest123, PID: 4804
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gametest.gametest123/com.gametest.gametest123.GamesActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast to com.gametest.gametest123.MyApplication
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast to com.gametest.gametest123.MyApplication
                                                                                       at com.gametest.gametest123.GamesActivity.onCreate(GamesActivity.java:124)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606) 
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.gametest.gametest123"
    android:versionCode="33"
    android:versionName="3.0.7" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

    <!-- Only this application can receive the messages and registration result -->
    <permission android:name="com.gametest.gametest123.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.gametest.gametest123.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive message -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Send the registration id to the server -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Generic permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- calldorado Permissions-->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" 
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" ><!--Calldorado XML analyzer inserted the attribute android:maxSdkVersion="22" in order to make the code compatible with the Google Play store-->
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" 
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" ><!--Calldorado XML analyzer inserted the attribute android:maxSdkVersion="22" in order to make the code compatible with the Google Play store-->
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/SHORT_APP_NAME"
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        tools:replace="android:label">



        <receiver
                android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.gametest.gametest123" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.gametest.gametest123.LocalNotification"></receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.gametest.gametest123.CloseApp"></receiver>

        <service android:name="com.gametest.gametest123.GCMIntentService" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.gametest.gametest123.activities.ViewApp"
            android:label="@string/SHORT_APP_NAME"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

        <activity
                android:name="com.gametest.gametest123.LoadViewApp"
                android:label="@string/SHORT_APP_NAME"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                />

        <activity
                android:name="com.gametest.gametest123.activities.OfferPage"
                android:label="@string/SHORT_APP_NAME"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                />

        <activity
            android:name="com.gametest.gametest123.discover.DiscoverApps"
            android:label="@string/TITLESTRING_WHATSNEW"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

        <activity
            android:name="com.gametest.gametest123.activities.ChooseMailClient"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

        <activity
                android:name="com.tapjoy.TJAdUnitActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
                android:name="com.tapjoy.mraid.view.ActionHandler"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity
                android:name="com.tapjoy.mraid.view.Browser"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity
                android:name="com.tapjoy.TJContentActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
                   android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                  android:configChanges=
                          "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                  android:label="@string/SHORT_APP_NAME"
                  tools:replace="android:theme"/>

        <!-- TODO: Fix -->
                  <!--android:label="@string/app_name" /-->

        <activity android:name="com.fyber.ads.ofw.OfferWallActivity"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />


        <!-- The GAMES activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.gametest.gametest123.GamesActivity"
            android:label="@string/SHORT_APP_NAME"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <provider
                android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1730237540533882"
                android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
                android:exported="true"/>

        <!-- Optionally, register AnalyticsReceiver and AnalyticsService to support background
     dispatching on non-Google Play devices -->
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
                  android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
                 android:enabled="true"
                 android:exported="false"/>

        <!-- Optionally, register CampaignTrackingReceiver and CampaignTrackingService to enable
             installation campaign reporting -->
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
                  android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MyApplication:

```
package com.gametest.gametest123;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    private Tracker mTracker;

    private Activity mCurrentActivity = null;

    public void setCurrentActivity(Activity mCurrectActivity) {
        this.mCurrentActivity = mCurrectActivity;
    }

    public Activity getCurrentActivity() {
        return mCurrentActivity;
    }

    private static Context mAppContext;

    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MultiDex.install(this);
        mInstance = this;
        this.setAppContext(getApplicationContext());
    }

    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return mAppContext;
    }

    public void setAppContext(Context mAppContext) {
        this.mAppContext = mAppContext;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the default {@link Tracker} for this {@link Application}.
     * @return tracker
     */
    synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
        if (mTracker == null) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
            mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.string.ga_trackingId);
        }
        return mTracker;
    }
}
```

GamesActivity up to the line where it crashes:

```
public class GamesActivity extends AndroidApplication implements DownloadAndParseJsonAppTask.DownloadAndParseJsonInterface, DialogInterface.OnCancelListener, PlayGames {

    private int mPresentNumber = 0;

    public ActionResolverAndroid actionResolverAndroid;
    public PlayGames mPlayGames;

    private boolean userIsWaitingForConnection = false;

    // Array to store all button elements initialized with 25 false elements (boolean is false by default, Boolean is null)
    private boolean[] mDoorsArray = new boolean[25];

    private DownloadAndParseJsonAppTask mTask;
    private Chartboost chartboost;

    // Loading data properties
    public ProgressDialog mLoadingDialog = null;
    public ArrayList<JsonData> mArrayJsonData;
    public String mLastModified = null;

    public Intent ofwIntent;
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 102;

    // Client used to interact with Google APIs
//    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    GameHelper gameHelper;

    public boolean loadUrl = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getADID();


        AndroidPermissions.check(this)
                .permissions(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                .hasPermissions(new Checker.Action0() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(String[] permissions) {
                        // do something..
                    }
                })
                .noPermissions(new Checker.Action1() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(String[] permissions) {
                        // do something..
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(GamesActivity.this
                                , new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}
                                , REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                })
                .check();

        // Load Google Analytics

        //THIS IS WHERE THE APP CRASHES
        ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getDefaultTracker();
```

Comment: You should provide a full stacktrace along with a comment in your code sample that indicates where the crash happens.

Comment: added both of those things, thanks

Comment: Although nothing stands out as the problem, there are numerous questionable things here: your application class extends MultiDexApplication, so it should not (does not) need to call `MultiDex.install(this)`, let alone _twice_. Your application should not be tracking the current activity. Setting a variable `mAppContext` as `getApplicationContext()` is pointless since `Application` _is_ the application context. Your Activity extends a class called `AndroidApplication`? Use your debugger, break at the line where it is crashing, and inspect the value of `getApplication()`.

Comment: yeah, I took over this from somebody else and am struggling to figure out all of these things they did that don't really add up, I did debug and on that line all I can tell about application is under this mApplication is equal to android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication

Comment: Can you confirm that you Application class's `onCreate` is - in fact - being called to create it as the app's Application class?

Comment: I put a breakpoint on onCreate of the Application and the debugger does not seem to go into the Application class. I tried removing the things you mentioned in Application, cleaning, rebuilding, and still nothing. Removing the call to the line causing the error, allows the app to run otherwise, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyApplication.getInstance(). getDefaultTracker();
```

Comment: did that and now I am getting a NullPointerException on the line instead

Answer (score 0):

All this points to the fact that your custom Application is not being set as the app's Application, which means there's something wrong with your manifest.

Double check your manifest and make sure you're editing the right manifest (there could be multiple in different flavors, especially since you have a `tools:replace` tag in there) and make sure your MyApplication class correctly.

If you don't find the problem, post your full manifest(s) and what folders / flavors they live in.

Comment: I added the full manifest. I checked the merged manifest and it had a warning that tools:replace for name and icon were not needed so removed those and just left label. The merged manifest matches this one with the application tag and the other manifests that I have in other modules are not contributing anything to the merged one. I also made a new project with everything as one module and only this manifest and still same error. I get the same cast error by making MyApplication extend Application as well, but it still says MultiDexApplication cast error though not Application, which is odd.

Comment: I also made a basic new project with just a MyApplication extending MultiDexApplication and only one activity and in that case it correctly called the MyApplication class.

Comment: After trying a bunch of things, removing   compile 'com.fyber:fyber-sdk:8.0.1' from my gradle file fixed the problem