# I am using the Android SDK for Agora.io and trying to implement live audio broadcasting.Getting error

Tags: android, agora.io

But when I am implementing in my application getting the following error.application is being crash.could you please help me!

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast to com.addemo.mdp.voice_test.AGApplication
                      at com.addemo.mdp.voice_test.ui.BaseActivity.checkSelfPermission(BaseActivity.java:108)
                      at com.addemo.mdp.voice_test.ui.BaseActivity.checkSelfPermissions(BaseActivity.java:85)
                      at com.addemo.mdp.voice_test.ui.BaseActivity.access$000(BaseActivity.java:38)
                      at com.addemo.mdp.voice_test.ui.BaseActivity$2.run(BaseActivity.java:75)

Please check my code in dropbox-https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrrq528mdrrt1ay/Voice_test.zip?dl=0

Comment: please check my code and give me solution if possible

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest.xml file name value should change ;

from:

```
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

to:

```
    android:name=".AGApplication"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your source code at

com.addemo.mdp.voice_test.AGApplication

And maybe you can check this to have a try.

[exception android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658796/exception-android-support-multidex-multidexapplication-cannot-be-cast-class?answertab=active#tab-top)

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex